# Spotlight Search - deep link integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, xcode7, corespotlight

I'm recieving results in spotlight but when the user taps on it, it only launches the app, I'm having trouble segueing to that specific product.

It would be much apprieated if someone can help me out!

Thanks!

Here is my code so far:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler {

    if ([userActivity.activityType isEqualToString:Identifier]) {

        UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: What part exactly is giving you difficulties in segueing? There are numeral variables here

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the `activityType` against the wrong value.

When launching an app from the spotlight, the activity type is `CSSearchableItemActionType` and the `userInfo` has a single key value pair `CSSearchableItemActionType` that contains your product identifier.

Simple Objective-C sample:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
    if ([userActivity.activityType isEqualToString:CSSearchableItemActionType])
    {
        NSString *uniqueIdentifier = userActivity.userInfo[CSSearchableItemActivityIdentifier];
        // do stuff to show detail for product with uniqueIdentifier
        return YES; // because you did handle the activity
    }
    return NO; // because you did NOT handle the activity
}
```

Simple Swift sample:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool
{

    if userActivity.activityType == CSSearchableItemActionType {
        let uniqueIdentifier = userActivity.userInfo[CSSearchableItemActivityIdentifier]
        // do stuff to show detail for product with uniqueIdentifier
        return true // because you did handle the activity
    }
    return false // because you did NOT handle the activity
}
```

Comment: He is perfect with NSUserActivity indexing which don't return CSSearchableItemActionType as activity type.

Comment: @guhan0 then if he is using NSUserActivity for a product detail he is using it wrong either way.

Answer (score 0):

Below checking may help you :

1. Check whether the *tabBarController* assigned properly or is it nil?
2. Is the UITabBarController delegate,*didSelectViewController* getting
   called ?
3. Later on,Debug the each navigation section using breaking    point
   and try to find out the issue